# How to use uppercase projectname in CDT template source file?

Tags: eclipse, templates, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have a working CDT template and it adds a file main_file.c to the source directory. Now I need to show project name in capital in the main_file.c, so I tried with its contents as:

```c
//This is $(projectName) project name in capital.
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Sample");
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code (as expected) shows project name as it was entered. But I want the project name to be displayed in Capitals, like if user gives test, the file should display TEST.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no corresponding eclipse variables for this.

The closest solution would be

- While creating  project use UPPER CASE.

OR

- After inserting the template(which used $(projectName) variable ) select the project name which is in lower case the press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: Is there any way by which I could achieve this? May be using process?

Comment: Only manual edit.IMO no other ways.Creating project name in UPPER case is also not recommended.At last you may tweak this code in JDT plugin.